# Instance member 'isFavorite' can't be accessed using static access

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem with bool isFavorite.

here are my codes:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_shop/providers/product.dart';

import 'package:my_shop/screens/product_detail_screen.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class ProductItem extends StatelessWidget {
this.title, this.imageUrl, {super.key});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final product = Provider.of<Product>(context);
return ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
  child: GridTile(
    footer: GridTileBar(
        title: Text(
          product.title,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          textScaler: const TextScaler.linear(2 / 3),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
              Product.isFavorite ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border),
          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
          onPressed: () {
            product.toggleFavoritestatus();
          },
        ),
        trailing: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
          onPressed: () {},
        )),
    child: GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
          ProductDetailScreen.routeName,
          arguments: product.id,
        );
      },
      child: Image.network(
        product.imageUrl,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```

the error is: Instance member 'isFavorite' can't be accessed using static access.dartstatic_access_to_instance_member
bool isFavorite
Type: InvalidType

package:my_shop/providers/product.dart

Please help me out.
thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you just to use `product.isFavorite` a typo here

Comment: can you share the `product` code

Comment: yes. you're right. that was a typo. thanks :)

Comment: Do you use an IDE? That should have been highlighted by it